# Combinatorics counting tuples

Tags: combinatorics

I have noticed that the number of 3-tuples $T$, that are such that $T_i \in [0,n]\; \forall i$ and $T_1+T_2+T_3 = n$ is exactly $(n^2+3n+2)/2$. For $n=3$ there are $10$ tuples:

$(0,0,3)\; (0,1,2)\; (1,0,2)\; (2,0,1)\; (0,2,1)\; (1,1,1)\; (1,2,0)\; (2,1,0)\; (0,3,0)\; (3,0,0)\; $

can you suggest me how to prove that this is true for every $n$?

Comment: **Hint:** $\binom{n+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{n+2}{2}=\dfrac{n^2+3n+2}{2}$.

Comment: Additional hint if the previous wasn't clear enough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really common question:

$$T_1+T_2+T_3=n$$

We can associate at each triple $(T_1,T_2,T_3)$ a binary number in this way:

$$(T_1,T_2,T_3) \rightarrow \underbrace{1..1}_{T_1}0\underbrace{1..1}_{T_2}0\underbrace{1..1}_{T_3} $$

Where the zeroes divide each "variable units" from the other ones. Our exercise is equivalent to calcute the number of permutations of $n$ ones and $2$ zeroes:

$$P_{n,2}=\frac{(n+2)!}{n!2!}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

What you are counting can be expressed as follows:

- What is the coefficient of $x^n$ of $(1+x+\cdots + x^n)^3$.

Now, lets use

- $1+x+\cdots + x^n= \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$
- $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2}{2}x^n$ which can be shown quickly by differentiating twice $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$

Now, lets calculate the coefficient of $x^n$:
\begin{eqnarray*} [x^n](1+x+\cdots + x^n)^3
& = & [x^n](1-x^{n+1})^3\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} \\
& = & [x^n]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+2}{2}x^k \\
& = & \binom{n+2}{2}\\
& = & \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}